# What are the subgroups of the projective general linear group of degree 3 over a finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, projective-space, linear-groups

I'm investigating something and the question of what the subgroups of $ \text{PGL}(3,\mathbb{F}_p)$ are has come up. I've found this [Group Properties Wiki page](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_projective_general_linear_group_of_degree_three_over_a_finite_field), but it doesn't contain much useful information. I'm not sure where I'd look for the answer to this sort of question, as it is not in the algebra textbooks I have at hand.

Comment: Use GAP or Magma.

Comment: See the paper [David M. Bloom, The Subgroups of PSL(3, q) for odd q](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1967-127-01/S0002-9947-1967-0214671-1/S0002-9947-1967-0214671-1.pdf), maybe you will find it useful.

Comment: @markvs GAP and Magma can only do the calculation for specific $p$, it cannot give a general answer.

Comment: Is there an answer to the general question? I thought - only specific and small $p$ can be handled.

Comment: Yes, the paper by David Bloom provides a complete answer. In fact, from the citations in that paper, you can see that the subgroups were described first for odd $q$ by Mitchell in 1911 and for even $q$ by Hartley for even $q$. But those older papers are written in a different style from what we are used to, and are very hard to read (I know because I once supervised a student project to read the Mitchell paper).

Comment: Having said that, I realize that these papers list the subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(3,q)$ rather than ${\rm PGL}(3,q)$, whcih can be three times larger, so there is an extra complication there. The maximal subgroups of all almost simple extensions of ${\rm PSL}(3,q)$ are known for all $q$, and they are indeed accessible from Magma (not sure about GAP).

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thank you! I did not know that.

Comment: @DerekHolt @ markvs Thank you so much for these resources! While having general answers for $\text{PGL}(3,q)$ would be nice, I'll see if the enumeration of $\text{PSL}$ has the answers I need. Otherwise, I can use this information and some computational investigation with GAP.